# Unable to start a program. Error in running console program in Visual Studio

Tags: c#

I am facing this error. Unable to start .The application has failed to start a program because the configuration is incorrect.

The code as follows

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] Words = new string[3];
        Words[0]= "Abba";
        Words[1] = "Dhappa";
        Words[3] = "Shavva";

        string a;
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter to get your desired string");
        a = Console.ReadLine();

        if (string.Equals(Words, a))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Equals");
        }


    }
```

Comment: It looks like a problem in your app.config file. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55385090/edit) your question and add app.config content

Comment: 1) `Words[3] = "Shavva"` will throw an `IndexOutOfRangeException`. 2) `string.Equals(Words, a)` will compile and run but will always return false because it will fall back to the `Object.Equals` method--`Words` is an array of strings, not a string. 3) I searched for the error message "*The application has failed to start a program because the configuration is incorrect.*" and got no results for that exact message (but plenty for similar messages). Please include the *actual* error message you're getting.